# How to send service account token in request to Google Cloud Functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dns, google-api-go-client

I'm running simple function in Google Cloud Functions to update DNS records ([see code here](https://github.com/tsaarni/dyndns-function)).  Currently I create service account with `roles/dns.admin` privileges and assign that to the function.  I'm then relying for Functions' beta support for client authentication & authorization.

Alternative approach could be NOT to provision the service account credentials (with `roles/dns.admin`) for the function, but instead pass credential in each request.

How can I do this with Go runtime - How can I use the bearer token from the request with the Google API Go client?

Pros/cons in these two approaches?

Comment: I guess one "pro" in the current implementation: client can be provisioned with service account with lesser privileges and with no direct access to CloudDNS, while function has full dns.admin privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to feed an access token originating from the request to the Google API Go client.  Here is how I construct the client (r is the incoming `http.Request`):

```golang
ctx := context.Background()

auth := r.Header.Get("Authorization")
token := strings.TrimPrefix(auth, "Bearer ")
ts := oauth2.StaticTokenSource(
    &oauth2.Token{AccessToken: token},
)
c := oauth2.NewClient(ctx, ts)

dnsService, err := dns.New(c)
```

But after thinking a bit, I do not think this is good approach in my case: the access token is unnecessarily powerful to give to the requester. So I chose the first approach in my original question.

Answer (score 1):

In GCF, you could request this to grab the token.

> curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"

Ref: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#applications

Comment: This is the token of service account that I have assigned to the function? The Google API Go client "DefaultClient" seems to get this automatically, but can I use the token from the client request instead? How to feed that to the Google API Go client?

Comment: I had used this method in Python to generate the HTTP request to Google API. You could change the request `header` with specified token. I suppose the Go Client should provide the method to update token, if not then you may try this approach.

Answer (score 0):

The Cloud Function should be able to use its credentials to authorize the request by getting the default credentials and passing it in the DNS client.

Find more info here: [Setting Up Authentication for Server to Server Production Applications](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-compute-engine-go)

Comment: Thanks!  I was actually looking on how to use alternative credentials stored at the external client, and I found a way now (I posted it as a separate answer to myself).  Though I have now decided to go back to the documented way since it gives more alternatives to secure the Function, such as the new [ESP with Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-functions)